# An application of Itô's formula to an SDE on a Lie group

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm trying to understand a calculation in [this](https://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/~marnaudo/publis/Arnaudon-Cruzeiro-Chen1.4893357.pdf) paper (equation (3.8)). With some details removed, the setup is as follows.

Let $G$ be a Lie group, and $g(t)$ a curve in $G$ satisfying the SDE

$$dg(t) = T_e L_{g(t)}H_1 dW_t + T_e L_{g(t)}H_2 dt + T_e L_{g(t)}u(t) dt,$$
where $H_1,H_2$ are elements of the Lie algebra, $u(t)$ is a curve in the Lie algebra, and $W_t$ is a real-valued brownian motion. The SDE / stochastic integrals are in the Stratonovich sense. My knowledge of processes and SDE's on manifolds are from Elton Hsu's [book](https://books.google.com/books/about/Stochastic_Analysis_on_Manifolds.html?id=2NM0Z7svRmEC). According to the construction in this book, a solution to an equation such as the above is defined by being a solution to the following euclidean SDE, for every smooth real-valued function *f* on *G*,

$$df(g(t)) = (T_e L_{g(t)}H_1)f\hspace{1mm} dW_t + (T_e L_{g(t)}H_2)f\hspace{1mm}dt + (T_e L_{g(t)}u(t))f \hspace{1mm} dt.$$

In the paper, they then consider a sort of perturbation of the curve *g*; $g(t)e_{\epsilon}(t)$, where e_{\epsilon}(t) is another curve in *G*. I don't think it is important to my question, but $e_\epsilon (t)$ is defined by a set of ODE's, equation (3.2) in the paper.

They then state that 'by Itö's formula' $g_\epsilon(t) := g(t) e_\epsilon(t)$ fulfills the SDE

$$dg_\epsilon(t) = T_e L_{g_\epsilon(t)}Ad_{e_{\epsilon}^{-1}(t)}(H_1) dW_t + T_e L_{g_\epsilon(t)}Ad_{e_{\epsilon}^{-1}(t)}H_2 dt + T_e L_{g_\epsilon(t)}Ad_{e_{\epsilon}^{-1}(t)}u(t) dt + T_e L_{g_\epsilon(t)} (T_{e_\epsilon (t)} L_{e^{-1}_\epsilon(t)}\dot{e}_\epsilon(t) dt $$

which (my calculation) is equivalent to

$$d(g(t) e_\epsilon (t)) = T_e (L_{g(t)}\circ R_{e_\epsilon (t)})H_1\hspace{1mm} dW_t + T_e (L_{g(t)}\circ R_{e_\epsilon (t)})H_2\hspace{1mm}dt + T_e (L_{g(t)}\circ R_{e_\epsilon (t)})u(t)  \hspace{1mm} dt + T_{e_\epsilon (t)} L_{g(t)} \dot{e}_\epsilon(t) dt\hspace{1mm}$$

I haven't been able to verify this, or find hints elsewhere. I have a feeling that I'm missing (or lack knowledge of) something very simple. Any hints would be greatly appreciated. Even if only for the deterministic case ($H_1 = 0$).

Answer (score 2):

To understand (3.8), I think it helps to write down (2.4) and (3.2) from [that](https://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/~marnaudo/publis/Arnaudon-Cruzeiro-Chen1.4893357.pdf) paper. From (3.2), note that $e_{\epsilon}(t)$ satisfies the ODE $$
\dot e_{\epsilon}(t) = \epsilon T L_{e_{\epsilon}(t)} \dot v(t) \;. \tag{1}
$$
By the Euclidean Itô-Stratonovich conversion formula applied in the Lie algebra, note from (2.4) that $g(t)$ satisfies the Itô SDE $$
d g(t) = T L_{g(t)} \left( \sum_i H_i dW^i_t + u(t) dt \right)  \;. \tag{2}
$$

Note also that the product rule for Itô processes applied to $g_{\epsilon}(t) = g(t) e_{\epsilon}(t)$ reduces to the standard product rule because $e_{\epsilon}(t)$ has finite variation.
Hence, from (1), (2), and the product rule, \begin{align}
d g_{\epsilon}(t)  &=  T R_{e_{\epsilon}(t)} d g(t)  + T L_{g(t)} \dot e_{\epsilon}(t) \\
&= T L_{g_{\epsilon}(t)} \left( \sum_{i} \operatorname{Ad}_{e_{\epsilon}(t)^{-1}} H_i dW^i_t +  \operatorname{Ad}_{e_{\epsilon}(t)^{-1}} u(t) dt \right) + \epsilon T L_{g_{\epsilon}(t)}  \dot v \tag{3}
\end{align}
where we used the identities \begin{align}
T R_{e_{\epsilon}(t)} \; T L_{g(t)} = T L_{g(t)} \; T R_{\epsilon(t)} = T L_{g_{\epsilon}(t)} \; \operatorname{Ad}_{e_{\epsilon}(t)^{-1}} \;, \qquad 
T L_{g(t)} \dot e_{\epsilon}(t)  = \epsilon T L_{g_{\epsilon}(t)} \dot v(t) \;.
\end{align}
Up to an Itô-Stratonovich correction term, (3) is exactly (3.8) in that paper.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However, I am new to these processes on Lie groups, so there are some things I need to understand before I can accept your answer. I will write my questions in comments below.

Comment: 1. I don't understand the notation $dg(t) = TL_{g(t)}(H_i dW_t + u(t) dt)$ (where $H_i$ is an element, and $u(t)$ a curve, in the Lie algebra), which is also used in the paper. Should it be understood as an equation for the differential of $g(t)$, as in $\frac{d}{ds}|_{s=t}\hspace{1mm} g(s) = RHS$? From reading the rest of the paper, I got the impression that it should be read as $g(t) = TL_{g(t)}(H_i) dW_t + TL_{g(t)}(u(t)) dt)$ (i.e. as integrals of the left-invariant vector fields on the manifold). Maybe these are equivalent viewpoints?

Comment: I realize now that all of my questions disappear if the interpretation of the LHS of (2) as $\dot{g}(t) = \frac{d}{ds}|_{s=t}g(s)$ is correct. I haven't seen this notation before (identifying stochastic differentials with actual differentials), do you have a reference for this? Or maybe it is specific to the type of equation above.

Comment: Lastly, a minor question: you write "Note also that the product rule for Itô processes applied to $g_{\epsilon}(t) = g(t) e_{\epsilon}(t)$ reduces to the standard product rule because $e_{\epsilon}(t)$ has finite variation.". But the Itô  product rule is not actually used in your calculation, is it? Only the product rule for the differential in a Lie group, as I understand your calculations. The Itô product rule, and the notion of finite variation of $e_\epsilon (t)$, isn't applicable for $g_\epsilon (t)$ and $e_\epsilon (t)$, since they are processes in the Lie group, right?

Comment: Regarding 1, please note that $T L_g$ denotes left multiplication by $g$ on elements of the tangent space of the Lie group $G$.  Hence, $T L_{g(t)}(H_i(g(t)) dW_t^i + u(t) dt)$ essentially "maps"  $H_i(g(t))$ and $u(t)$ belonging to the Lie algebra, i.e., $T_e G$, into the tangent space of the Lie group at $g(t)$, i.e., $T_{g(t)} G$.  The point of doing that is to obtain an SDE on the Lie group by taking a standard one on the Lie algebra and left translating it to obtain one on $G$.  The interpretation of the LHS of (2) is the integral version of (2) — exactly as in the Euclidean case.

Comment: Regarding the product rule, the reason why the Itô product rule simplifies is because one of the terms in the product is a function of finite variation, and hence, the covariation term in the Itô product rule vanishes, leaving the standard one.

Comment: Regarding 1: but if we interpret the LHS of (2) as in the euclidean case, then the LHS is just $g(t)$ (?). But then the LHS is a process in $G$ while the RHS is a process in $T_{g(t)}G$? Or do you mean that $\int^t_0 dg(s)$ is defined, and is an element of $T_{g(t)}G$? In Hsu's sense of the stochastic integral on manifolds, we can only integrate wrt. euclidean processes, so some other definition must be at play.

Comment: Regarding the product rule. My question was about the fact that $g(t)$ and $e_\epsilon (t)$ take values in the Lie group, so are you using an Itô product rule (and a definition of finite variation) for such Lie group-valued processes?

Comment: Another comment: the last element of (3) above is $\epsilon TL_{g_\epsilon (t)} \dot{v}(t)$, but in (3.8) in the paper it is $\epsilon TL_{g_\epsilon (t)} \dot{v}(t) dt$, so something doesn't add up.

Comment: Regarding your point on $\epsilon T L_{g_{\epsilon}(t)} \dot v(t)$, yes that's a typo.  MO is not really intended for long discussion. In view of this, I'm not sure what else I can say beyond: they define an SDE on the Lie group by left translating a standard Euclidean  Itô SDE on the Lie algebra.   Maybe you can work it out in several simple examples like  $SO(2)$ or $SE(2)$ to understand this statement better?